# Can I add PHP Zip to a Laravel project using composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, zip

I need to use the PHP zip extension in a Laravel project.  The PHP manual talks about building PHP with the zip extension, http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php.

My environments all run on Ubuntu, though on differing versions.  I see plenty of articles talking about using apt-get to install the extension.

I'm pretty sure that I can use composer to manage this extension, but I can't find any articles on it.  Can I do this?  How do I add it?  I would prefer to use composer if possible.

Comment: `php-zip` is PHP's core extension while `composer` is project's dependencies management, I pretty sure that you can't install `php-zip` using `composer`. Why don't you use `apt-get` to install it?

Comment: I tried apt-get in one environment, but my IDE did not recognise that it was installed.

Comment: I believe that's just the warning from IDE but your app run fine. If your project require php-zip to run add `"ext-zip": "*"` to your composer requirement. It won't install php-zip when you run `composer install` but it will check for php-zip extension and throw error if it's not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found this on the composer site:

> Composer has platform packages, which are virtual packages for things
>   that are installed on the system but are not actually installable by
>   Composer. This includes PHP itself, PHP extensions and some system
>   libraries.

It can not do the install, but presumably adding the ext reference to composer.json will give satisfy my IDE.